# How to convert a worksheet to a Data frame in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read different worksheets from an Excel workbook in Python with  Pandas. When I read the entire workbook and then I want to apply a .merge() then the first worksheet is read but the others are not considered. I tried to read each worksheet of the workbook but I guess they were not successfully converted to data frames because when I apply .merge() I end up with the following error: `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

This is what I have done so far:

## This code works for converting the entire workbook to a data frame but only the data of the first worksheet is processed

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc

#sql extractor
start_date = date.today()
retrieve_values = "[DEV].[CS].[QT_KPIExport] @start_date='{start_date:%Y-%m-%d}'".format(
    start_date=start_date)
connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="X",pwd="xxx", Trusted_Connection="No")
data_frame_sql = pd.read_sql(retrieve_values, connection)

#Read the entire workbook 
wb_data = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Testing\\Daily_Data\\NSN-Daily Data Report.xlsx")
#Convert to a dataframe the entire workbook
data_frame_excel = pd.read_excel(wb_data,index_col=None,na_values=['NA'],parse_cols="J")

#apply merge
merged_df   = data_frame_sql.merge(data_frame_excel,how="inner",on="sectorname")
```

### This code tries to read the different worksheets and convert them to data frames with no success...yet! (check the answer below)

```
data_frame_sql = pd.read_sql(retrieve_values, connection)

#Method 1: Tried to parse worksheet 2
#Read the entire workbook and select the specific worksheet
wb_data = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Testing\\Daily_Data\\NSN-Daily Data Report.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet-2")
data_frame_excel = pd.read_excel(wb_data,index_col=None,na_values=['NA'],parse_cols="J")

#apply merge
merged_df   = data_frame_sql.merge(data_frame_excel,how="inner",on="sectorname")
#No success... the data of the first sheet is read

#Method 2: Tried to parse worksheet 2
#Read the entire workbook
wb_data = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Testing\\Daily_Data\\NSN-Daily Data Report.xlsx")
data_frame_excel = pd.read_excel(wb_data,index_col=None,na_values=['NA'],parse_cols="J")

#select one specific sheet
ws_sheet_2 = wb_data.parse("Sheet-2")

#apply merge
merged_df   = data_frame_sql.merge(ws_sheet_2,how="inner",on="sectorname")
# No success.... ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all worksheets from a workbook into a dictionary by using the sheetname=None argument with the read_excel method.  Key/value pairs will be ws name/dataframe.

```
ws_dict = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', sheetname=None)
```

Note the sheetname argument will change to sheet_name in future pandas versions...

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution that did the trick.

```
#Method 1: Add the sheetname once you have read the entire workbook 
#Read the entire workbook 
wb_data = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Testing\\Daily_Data\\NSN-Daily Data 
Report.xlsx")
#Select your sheetname to read 
data_frame_excel = pd.read_excel(wb_data,index_col=None,na_values=
['NA'],parse_cols="J" sheetname="Sheet-2")

#apply merge
merged_df   = 
data_frame_sql.merge(data_frame_excel,how="inner",on="sectorname")
```

Answer (score 0):

To read *.xlsx* files in Pandas, for a document with multiple sheets, specify the sheet name and use a different engine.

Step 1 (install the *openpyxl* package):

```
! pip install openpyxl
```

Step 2 (use the *openpyxl* engine):

```
data_df = pd.read_excel(<ARCHIVE_PATH>, sheetname= <sheet_name>, engine='openpyxl')
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel) is the official documentation.

Another solution using *openpyxl* directly:

```
wb = load_workbook(ARCHIVE_PATH)
ws = wb[<sheet-name>]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_tm = sheet.values
coluna_tm = next(df_tm)[0:]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_tm, columns=coluna_tm)
```