# Extracting Data from an Imported Excel File on Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been taking a course that shows how to use Seaborn and matplotlib on Jupiter in order to create various data visualization models. I also just learned how to import excel files into Jupiter but the problem I am having is that the data cannot be taken out of the excel file as it is not a data frame.

Does anyone know how to extract data from an imported excel file so that it can be used in data visualization? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a worksheet to a Data frame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310787/how-to-convert-a-worksheet-to-a-data-frame-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. There is a method called [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) that reads .xls files easily.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
df = pd.read_excel('name.xlsx') # reads the excel file
sns.scatterplot(x="xvar",y="yvar",data=df) # creates a scatter plot with columns xvar and yvar
```

Then you can directly use pandas data frames to visualize data using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html) library.